# Transform filter cannot connect hevc/AVI file to renderer

Tags: directshow, avi, hevc

I have made a transform filter for hevc codec .It is getting connect for other media file format but with avi file it is not connecting on output side to renderer. I thought the  issue was with respect to dynamic format change but even after implementing that piece code there is no change.

This are links which i followed:
[BITMAPINFOHEADER Structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms779712(VS.85).aspx), 
[QueryAccept (Upstream)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377489(v=vs.85).aspx)

even i observed in filter input property that the size of bimapinfoheader member biSize is 108. i did not understand how to use this info.

Is there anyway to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can save hevc in an avi format, because avi does not support b-frames and variable framerates.

As it is stated in the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318188(v=vs.85).aspx), the avi muxer only allows Guids in an [old style FOURCC format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375796(v=vs.85).aspx).